# Electrolaser speculation

Tags: electromagnetism

So I was thinking of a situation that could only exist in the future when we are able to create very strong electrolasers that could ionize the air upwards of a few kilometers. So my question is if someone had such a device and they aimed it at a thunderstorm cloud creating a conductive plasma channel and draining the static potential energy from the cloud what would happen?

Comment: What is an electrolaser?

Comment: Electrolasers use high energy UV light to ionize the air allowing electricity to be conducted along the beam.

Comment: What would happen? Well, you laser would be subjected to a lightning strike, which probably isn't too good for it... And, why do you think strong UV lasers are a thing of the future only?